# Can't reference dataset in visual studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, dataset

For some reason I'm getting an error that basically states that it can't find my DataSet in my project when clearly it is there. I've attached a screenshot, notice the red squares that I've drawn on the screenshot. My datasource is there, my database is there, but still getting error in code.

[image]

Getting really frustrating!!
Is there something that I'm missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your dataset is in your project does not mean you can reference it in your class. You need to create an instance of the dataset in your class.

```
HonestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet yourDataSet = new HonestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet();
```

EDIT: typo in my original post, if you just copy/pasted it before, try it now.

Comment: This doesn't work, doesn't recognize they type/class HonestRalphsUsedCars... Since there is no class in my project with that name..

Comment: How did you create your dataset?

Comment: This is what I did: I went to Data > Add New Data Source > Chose Database > Chose Dataset > New Connection > Chose 'Microsoft Access Database File' as datasource, and then browsed and pointed to the database file on my machine and clicked done..

Comment: okay your answer took care of the error and I'm able to run my project. Although now when I run my program and it's just not finding any data, no run time errors, nothing. When you create a new instance of my datasource, should one parse any arguments?

Comment: You need to fill the dataset with data - see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or right mouse click on yr file, and select compile in the build action

Comment: Thanks, what file exactly though?